# Xamarin in VS 2017 ramp up: cant drag a button from toolbox

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

At first I had errors related to NuGet packages, now my system is stable, or at least I don't see errors displayed.

The problem: When I select (Button, for example) from the tool box to the layout of activity_main.axml, the system wont let me drop it, showing "no entry" sign.
[image]
Any idea what did I miss?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eMj3.jpg)

Comment: why not use 2019? and you it will work only if the parent layout supports adding children.

Comment: I will move to 2019, but currently in deployment of a c# project. So I prefer not to change while deploying. I assume 2 months from now. I am new to Xamarin. I want to drag a button to the parent, not a child window.

Comment: It could you either they way you are doing, or the VS 2017 issue. You should post gif or axml code and show which part of the screen you are dragging element to. If there is an issue it wont belong to stackoverflow most probably, then you would have to raise issue at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: Please chanage your `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`, You can drag the button to your layout.

Comment: Thanks @LeonLu-MSFT. this helped.  I also added android:orientation="vertical" to the activityMain.axml. Both changes needed to the out of the box project.

Comment: Can I move above comment to anwser? and you mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @ Leon Lu - MSFT   Yes please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please chanage your `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`, And added `android:orientation="vertical"` to the `activityMain.axml`

You can drag the button to your layout like this gif.
[image]